# Linux: Can I build a shortcut for a complex cd command without resorting to a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash

On a server I work on, I always have to work in a directory, let's call it `/foo/bar`. In that directory is a list of site directories. Inside each of *those* directories is a directory for each developer. So, the tree looks like this:

```
/foo/bar/
         site1/
               userA/
               userB/
               userC/
         site2/
               userA/
               userB/
               userC/
         site3/
               userA/
         ...
```

I set up an alias for the root directory in my .bash_profile, `fb=/foo/bar`, so my workflow looks like this:

```
$ cd $fb
$ cd site2
$ cd userA
```

The first and third lines never change--I'm always going to go to the `userA` directory of whatever site directory I change to.

My question: Is there a clever way I can compress this into a single command that I just pass the "site2" argument without having to build this into a shell script? Or is the shell script the only way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something with a bash function

```
site() {
    cd /foo/bar/site${1}/userA
}
```

Put that in your .bashrc and then call it like

```
site 2
```

it will take you to /foo/bar/site2/userA

Comment: I don't find there's any meaningful difference between a function and a separate script... but this is really the way to do this. Multiple aliases a-la Steve Will's suggestion works too but doesn't require any less work to set up. Personally I use both: lots of discrete cd aliases for specific directories, and functions for patterned directory changes.

Comment: @SuperMagic: Probably, an alias/function is faster to setup than a script as you probably have a shortcut in your editor to go to that file. Also, those are typically short, and you don't want one million one-liner scripts. It is also easier to copy one `.rc` file to a new system than to bring over a script folder and changing the `PATH`. But the other thing you wrote (last sentence) is exactly what I do, and I think it is as good a way as any.

Answer (score 3):

Use a bash function like this.

```
function myCD() {
   local site
   local user
   case $# in
     0)  read -p site: site
         read -p user: user
         ;;
     1|2)
        site=${1}
        user=${2:-userA}
        ;;
    *)
       echo "don't accept more as 2 arguments" >&2
       return 1
       ;;
   esac
   cd ${fb}/${site}/${user}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could probably just use an alias like

```
alias site2="cd /foo/bar/site2/userA"
```

You also might want to look into the CDPATH environment variable. See the man page for your shell.

Answer (score 2):

Just link them into your home directory:

```
ln -s /foo/bar/site{$1}/userA ~/workspace/$1
```

That way, they will all appear local to you. No need to faff about until a new site is added.

Or, do what I do: 
Mount them onto my local workstation via SSH directly into my home-dir..  IDE's and whatnot being what they are, it is generally more efficient.

```
mkdir ~/workspace/site1
sshfs -o idmap=user $USER@server:/foo/bar/baz/site1/userA ~/workspace/site1
```

To unmount,

```
fusermount -u ~/workspace/site1
```

From [ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS)

Pop that into your login script, bingo, all your work-base are belong to us!